# Amazon MSK cluster on private VPC access with TLS enabled

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, amazon-vpc, ssh-tunnel, aws-msk

I have an AWS MSK kafka cluster on a private VPC. I have set up a bastion to connect to this cluster and can successfully produce and consume messages from the bastion using kafka console commands and using the JVM keystore for SSL auth.

I am trying to produce/consume messages via a SSH tunnel from my mac -> bastion -> kafka broker but I cant seem to get it working.

This is my SSH tunnel command:
`ssh  -i ~/bastion.pem  -N ec2-user@ec2-myhost.compute.amazonaws.com -L 9094:kafkacluster.amazonaws.com:9094 -v`

and then locally on my mac I run `kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9094 --producer.config client.properties --topic mytopic` but get `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic AWSKafkaTutorialTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms` errors.

I dont get this error when I use the zookeeper server which is not TLS enabled.

So my question is: how can I make this SSH tunnel work when the kafka client is connecting to localhost:9094 with SSL enabled?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @aamirnshah did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be that when you are in the vpc you are using the AWS dns and kafka may be doing some fancy redirects to other parts of the kafak cluster so kafkacluster.amazonaws.com might go to b1-kafka-blah.amazonaws.com etc.

```
# On Mac - aws internal dns name means nothing
#
localhost:9094 ---over-ssh---> kafka
    (kafka says, hey go to blah.amazon.com)
blah.amzon.com (dns has no idea, fails with errors)
```

However, this works fine in your vpc as you are within the aws dns namespace.

When you are on your mac, you are not in that namespace, and that dns has no meaning.

A sneaky thing you can do is edit your /etc/hosts and point the dns of these unknown names back to your localhost.  (For services on other ports, you'll need more tunnels)

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost blah.amazon.com blah-01.amazon.com
```

This will trick your mac into going over the tunnel rather than trying to use the dns lookup.

Obviously, this is a bit naughty.  Just use it for testing and remember to change your hosts file back to normal after.

It could also be that you have a different issue altogether.  Good luck.